# How to fix boostrap layout with long fixed navbar?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a bootstrap 3.x layout with fixed navbar.
If menu is too long header (class page-header) is not visible because menu is too height. See [print screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMbM2.png)

```
<body>      
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>              
          <li><a href="#contact">Test #1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Test #2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Test #3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Test #4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Test #5</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Test #6</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Test #7</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Test #8</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Test #9</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>          
    </div>
  </nav> 
  <div class="container">
    <div class="page-header">
      <h1>Sticky footer with fixed navbar</h1>
    </div>
    <p class="lead">Test</p>
    <p>Back to <a href="../sticky-footer">the default sticky footer</a> minus the navbar.</p>
  </div>    
  <footer class="footer">
    <div class="container">
      <p class="text-muted">Place sticky footer content here.</p>
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>
```

Please see example: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lukaszp/f8ute6cc/1/)
I don't know how long will be menu (it's code generated and depends on user rights).
I only need to if menu will be too height, the content should go down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution of this problem. You can do it by `jquery`. Below the code is

```
var nav_height = $('.navbar-fixed-top').height();
$('body').css('padding-top',nav_height );
```

check the live demo on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f8ute6cc/4/)

Comment: Really nice trick! I will include this code in function called resizeToNavbar and run this code after page load and window resize
`$(window).resize(function () {
        resizeToNavbar();
    });`

Comment: After vote I get message: _Thanks for the feedback! Once you earn a total of 15 reputation, your votes will change the publicly displayed post score._
Thanks for solution!